# SQL Select - transform rows in columns

Tags: sql, informix

Quite basic, but I am stuck at the moment.

On an Informix database (no pivot option), I am searching for a dynamic way to transform the following table using SQL:

```
book       | info  | value
-----------------------------
Moby Dick  | price | high
Moby Dick  | stock | few
Hamlet     | price | low
Hamlet     | stock | many
Faust      | price | medium
Faust      | stock | normal
```

Resulting table:

```
book       | price  | stock
-----------------------------
Moby Dick  | high   | few
Hamlet     | low    | many
Faust      | medium | normal
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate based on `CASE` expression grouped by book. Try something like this.

```
SELECT book,
MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'price' THEN value END) as price,
MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'stock' THEN value END) as stock
FROM table1
GROUP BY book
```

Comment: Right, but my value is actually a string. Bad example, I change it.

Comment: Use `MAX` in that case