# SQL Select - combine two tables (while transforming rows in columns)

Tags: sql, informix

Next step from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246875/sql-select-transform-rows-in-columns):

On an Informix database (no pivot option), I am searching for a dynamic way to transform the following tables using SQL:

First table: "catalog"

```
book       | info  | value
-----------------------------
Moby Dick  | price | high
Moby Dick  | stock | few
Hamlet     | price | low
Hamlet     | stock | many
Faust      | price | medium
Faust      | stock | normal
```

Second table: "artists"

```
book       | author
------------------------------------------
Moby Dick  | Herman Melville
Hamlet     | William Shakespeare
Faust      | Johann Wolfgang von Goethe
```

The resulting table, which I want to achieve:

```
book       | price  | stock  | author
-------------------------------------------------------------
Moby Dick  | high   | few    | Herman Melville
Hamlet     | low    | many   | William Shakespeare
Faust      | medium | normal | Johann Wolfgang von Goethe
```

The code I have in mind so far to reach the resulting table looks as follows. 
Combining two tables:

```
SELECT T1.book,
       T1.info,
       T1.value,
       T2.book,
       T2.author
FROM catalog T1,
     artists T2
WHERE T1.book=T2.book
```

Transforming rows to columns:

```
SELECT book,
MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'price' THEN value END) as price,
MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'stock' THEN value END) as stock
FROM catalog
GROUP BY book
```

But unfortunately, I am unable to combine those two.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Im not sure what you have and what you want ..... `I Have this` give you `Resulting Table`? What is your desire output?

Comment: I want the resulting table. The code is where I stand right now. I try to make it more clear.

Comment: So what is your current query and result? So we can see what is wrong now and tell you how go to your desire result. Because in your other question you say was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/114b30b/4)

```
SELECT T1.book,
       MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'price' THEN value END) as price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN info = 'stock' THEN value END) as stock,
       MAX(T2.author) as author
FROM catalog T1
JOIN artists T2
  ON T1.book = T2.book
GROUP BY T1.book;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|      book |  price |  stock |                     author |
|-----------|--------|--------|----------------------------|
|     Faust | medium | normal | Johann Wolfgang von Goethe |
|    Hamlet |    low |   many |        William Shakespeare |
| Moby Dick |   high |    few |            Herman Melville |
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to do the aggregation before doing the `join`, like this:

```
select a.book, c.price, c.stock, a.author
from artists a left join
     (select c.book,
             max(case when info = 'price' then value end) as price,
             max(case when info = 'stock' then value end) as stock
      from catalog c
      group by c.book
     ) c
     on a.book = c.book;
```

Or, you can `join` first and then aggregate:

```
SELECT a.book,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.info = 'price' THEN c.value END) as price,
       MAX(CASE WHEN c.info = 'stock' THEN c.value END) as stock,
       a.author
FROM catalog c JOIN
     artists a
     ON c.book = a.book
GROUP BY a.book, a.author;
```